# Mathematics with large factorials (e.g. division?)

Tags: c++, factorial

I'm trying to find the percentage of permutations of 100 numbers that contain cycles of length more than 50. This involves mathematics consisting of division with large factorials which can't be done by hand very quickly, so I need to resort to programming. For instance one these term contains

(3!/100!)*((99!/3!) + (98!/2!) + (97!/1!) + (96!/0!))

I *could* re-arrange all terms to provide one large number (>2^64) that just needs to be divided by 100! to get my answer.

I've thought for quite a bit, still being new to C++, and I'm not sure how I can do division with large numbers. Normally when I've dealt with large factorials I've output digits of the number in to an array and done multiplication through that, but I'm not entirely sure how to do division that way. What is the best way to deal with mathematics of large numbers in C++?

Comment: http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7349/computing-factorials-of-a-huge-number-in-cc-a-tutorial (and plenty of other links, google it yourself )

Comment: Read about [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) and consider using [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/). Alternatively, do some arithmetic reasoning to simplify your expression.

Comment: You should also consider using a computer algebra system, Maple, Mathematica, Sage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious from the structure of the equation (a reciprocal of a very large factorial multiplied with some large factorials with about the same magnitude) that a lot of cancellation can happen. That means that this problem can be solved with some very simple algebra and with a bit of extra luck even without any kind of computation.

Let's replace the factorials with some innocent little letters to avoid intimidation by the large numbers.

With 0! = 1 by definition and 1!=1 we can skip these values and use the following substitutions:

a = 2!, b = 3!, v = 96!, w = 97!, x = 98!, y = 99!, z = 100!

That gives

```
(b/z)*(y/b + x/a + w + v)
```

expand

```
b*(y/b + x/a + w + v) * 1/z
```

expand numerator (let's use some ASCII art for legibility)

```
                      b*x
 y +  (b*w) + (b*v) + ---
                       a
 ------------------------
            z
```

squeeze it all in one fraction

```
(a*y) + (a*b*w) + (a*b*v) + (x*b)
---------------------------------
             (a*z)
```

take it apart

```
 a*y     a*b*w     a*b*v     x*b 
----- + ------- + ------- + -----
 a*z      a*z       a*z      a*z
```

Yepp, looks good, we can put the numbers back in

```
 2!*99!       2!*3!*96!       2!*3!*97!      3!*98!
--------- + ------------- + ------------- + ---------
 2!*100!       2!*100!         2!*100!       2!*100!
```

First round of cancellations (could have already been done at the letter stage)

```
  99!      3!*96!      3!*97!     3!*98!
------ + ---------- + -------- + --------
 100!       100!        100!      2!*100!
```

The factorials cancel each other out, but only partially

First step

```
 1         1*2*3        1*2*3     1*2*3
---  + ------------ + --------- + ------
100    97*98*99*100   98*99*100   1*2*99*100
```

Second step

```
 1           1            1          1
---  + ------------ + -------- + -------
100    97*98*33*50    98*33*50   2*33*50
```

Common denominator

```
97*98*33*50*2 + 100*2 + 100*97*2 + 100*97*98
--------------------------------------------
           100*97*98*33*50*2
```

Massage numerator a bit by factoring out 100

```
97*98*33*50*2 + 100*(2*98 + 97*98)
----------------------------------
       100*97*98*33*50*2
```

Part

```
  97*98*33*50*2      100*(2*98 + 97*98)
----------------- + -------------------
100*97*98*33*50*2    100*97*98*33*50*2
```

Cancel

```
 1     2*98 + 97*98
--- + --------------
100   97*98*33*50*2
```

Part

```
 1        2*98             97*98
--- + -------------- + --------------
100   97*98*33*50*2    97*98*33*50*2
```

Cancel

```
 1        1          1
--- + -------- + -------
100   97*33*50   33*50*2
```

And we have on summand less and got rid of the 98. Rinse and repeat until the final result is found:

```
  1
 ----
  97
```

Yes, sometimes a sharp pencil and a blank sheet of paper is all you need ;-)